# Обрезать строку регулярным выражением

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

У меня есть две строки:

```
<a href="/kp/pioneer-woman-glasses?cat_id=11327&create_ids=top-rtd-the-pioneer"></a>
<a href="/kp/pioneer-woman-glasses?query=glasses&cat_id=11327&create_ids=top-rtd-the-pioneer"></a>
```

Помогите обрезать строку через регулярное выражение, чтобы обрезать `/kp/pioneer-woman-glasses` до `?query` или `?cat_id`

Пробовал `~a href=\"(.+?)(query|cat_id)~im`, но оно не оставляет `a href`

Comment: покажите, что должно быть на выходе.

Comment: дополните вопрос, в какой функции применяете регулярку? И да, где ожидаемый вывод?

Comment: На выходе надо получить: 
<a href="?cat_id=11327&create_ids=top-rtd-the-pioneer"></a>
<a href="?query=glasses&cat_id=11327&create_ids=top-rtd-the-pioneer"></a>

Comment: @Юрий я написал решение, посмотрите в моем ответе

Answer (score 2, accepted):

str_replace

```
$str = "<a href='/kp/pioneer-woman-glasses?cat_id=11327&create_ids=top-rtd-the-pioneer'></a>";
$res = str_replace('/kp/pioneer-woman-glasses', '', $str);
echo $res;
```

regEx

```
$str = "<a href='/kp/pioneer-woman-glasses?cat_id=11327&create_ids=top-rtd-the-pioneer'></a>";
$res = preg_replace("/\/kp(.+?)(ses)/", "", $str );
echo $res;
```

Comment: Можете написать ответ, если в URl идёт не только pioneer-woman-glasses, а например cars

Comment: preg_replace("/\/kp(.+?)(ses|cars)/", "", $str );

Comment: помогло вам????

Comment: да, спасибо помогло